# Define a custom json serializer for springfox swagger2 for @ApiOperations

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have a simple rest api, with single GET method implemented. I would like to have it documented using springfox and swagger. All is very easy expect sample response.

By default springfox uses reflection based serializer - produces a simple json with all public fields of java class - I would like to change this behavior and use custom serializer.

Here is my controller (most of the code is simplified for the sake of the question):

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping( value = "/GetResponse", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public Response getResponse( )  {
        return Response.randomInstance();
    }

}
```

Response class is runtime generated - I cannot edit/modify that class, so annotations like @ApiModelProperty are not feasible. By default I use custom serializer (StaticResponseConverter is also auto generated):

```
@JsonComponent
public  class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<Response> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Response response, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {
        generator.writeRaw( StaticResponseConverter.toJson(response) );
    }
}
```

This serializer works without issues for regular api calls. However, it is not used by swagger2 when producing a sample response.

Swagger config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        return new Docket( DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2 ).select()
                .apis( x -> x.declaringClass().equals( Controller.class ) ).paths( PathSelectors.any() )
                .build();
    }
}
```

I tried this approach:

[Spingfox not recognizing custom serializer when generating JSON model for swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728778/spingfox-not-recognizing-custom-serializer-when-generating-json-model-for-swagge)

There is also this approach, but I'm unable to apply it to springfox.

[Swagger is it possible to override custom object serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677498/swagger-is-it-possible-to-override-custom-object-serialization)

Maven config:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

How to make springfox/swagger to  use my custom json serializer when generating sample response for swagger-ui.html.

Comment: I second the approach provided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39918957/19219).

Answer (score 1):

I second the approach provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918957/19219) to provide a model via:

- a `directModelSubstitute` or
- a `genericModelSubsitute` or
- Supply an alternate type rule.

What this does is helps the springfox schema inference engine with what it is not able to infer. Using a serializer is opaque to jackson and hence to springfox as well. This is because its very difficult to know how a particular type is serialized/deserialized over the wire by inspecting the *implementation* of a serializer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to provide a model substitute, sine Response class is runtime generated one (together with StaticResponseConverter).

Forgot to mention it in the question, edited.

Comment: Granted that it will not be used as a DTO and its sole purpose of existence would be to provide the schema for the response, you should still be able to create a dummy class that represents what the serialized object would look like. Its similar to a [jackson Mixin](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)